# How to make a Grails richui g:autocomplete field mandatory

Tags: javascript, grails, autocomplete, gsp, required

I can't see any way to make a `richui autocomplete` in `grails` mandatory.  With a `g:select` I'd just use `required="required"` but this doesn't appear to work for g:autocompletes, any suggestions?

Currently my autocomplete looks like so...

```
<richui:autoComplete required="required" style="width:500px" name="autoLook[X].id" id="autoLook[X]." value="" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'object/searchAJAX')}" forceSelection = "true" maxResultsDisplayed="20" minQueryLength ="3" onItemSelect="updateHiddenInput(id,X)" />
```

Is the only way of doing this going to be running a javascript check before submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `required="required"` when page is ready, like:

Add class `required` in the `richui:autoComplete`

```
<richui:autoComplete class="required" name="name[${idx}]" id="uniqueId[${idx}]" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'oauthCallBack/test')}" onItemSelect="updateHiddenInput(id, this)"/>
```

and script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.required').each(function (index) {
            jQuery(this).attr('required', 'required')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Added this into my document.ready and updated my element and it works like a charm cheers!  I also need to apply it to extra elements added via AJAX during runtime but that should be simple enough to do, cheers!!! :)

Comment: Probably a little hacky but I just stuck it in `$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
           $('.required').each(function (index) {
                jQuery(this).attr('required', 'required')
            });` and this then updates them all after the ajax inserts and that does the job nicely too :)